# Rename files using regular expression in linux : suppress part of string

Tags: regex, linux, rename

I have a set of files named like:

```
Greys.Anatomy.05x15.Before.and.After.BluRay.fr.srt
Greys.Anatomy.05x16.bla.bla.fr.srt
...
Greys.Anatomy.05x24.bla.bla.fr.srt
```

and I want to rename them like the following

```
Greys.Anatomy.05x15.fr.srt
Greys.Anatomy.05x16.fr.srt
...
Greys.Anatomy.05x24.fr.srt
```

what should I do to make the job done in linux terminal? I have installed rename but nothing work with

```
rename -n 's/(\w+)\.(\d{1})x(\d{2}).*$/S0$2E$3\.srt/' *.srt
```

Comment: Please follow the How to Ask guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your chances of having an adequate answer. Specifically, post what you attempted and any specific failures you faced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` utility like this:

```
rename 's/^(.*?\d+x\d+).*?(\.fr\.srt)$/$1$2/' *srt
```